# Bash while loop stops after first iteration when subshell is called

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, subshell

This contrived bash script demonstrates the issue.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r node ; do
    echo checking $node for Agent;
       PID=$(ssh $node ""ps -edf | grep [j]ava | awk '{print $2}'"")
       echo $PID got to here.
done < ~/agents_master.list
```

agents_master.list contains 1 server per line:

```
server1
server2
server3
```

Which only outputs the following:

```
checking server1 for Agent
Authorized use only
25176 got to here
```

Server 2 and 3 aren't even echoed out to screen by the line `echo checking $node...`

If I comment out the line `PID=$(....` then the while completes the whole agents_master.list file correctly...

```
checking server1 for Agent
got to here
checking server2 for Agent
got to here
checking server3 for Agent
got to here
```

From the googling I've done, it sounds like this is related to the subshell that `$(...)` creates, but I don't understand why it is causing the loop to stop at the first server, `server1`.

Yes, this code could be re-written but I'm keen to understand this behaviour of bash and why this is happening for future.

Comment: `PID=$(ps -edopid=,command= | awk '/[j]ava/{print $1}')` saves you a pipe and wasted process. Assuming you're in Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem -- one of the problems -- is that `ssh` is forwarding stdin to the remote server. As it happens, the command you are running on the remote server (`ps -edf`, see below) doesn't use its standard input, but ssh will still forward what it reads, just in case. As a consequence, nothing is left for `read` to read, so the loop ends.

To avoid that, use `ssh -n` (or redirect input to `/dev/null` yourself, which is what the `-n` option does).

There are a couple of other issues which are not actually interfering with your scripts execution.

First, I have no idea why you use `""` in

```
ssh $node ""ps -edf | grep [j]ava | awk '{print $2}'""
```

The `""` "expands" to an empty string, so the above is effectively identical to

```
ssh $node ps -edf | grep [j]ava | awk '{print $2}'
```

that means that the `grep` and `awk` commands are being run on the local host; the output from the `ps` command is forwarded back to the local host by `ssh`. That doesn't change anything, although it does make the brackets in `[j]ava` redundant, since the `grep` won't show up in the process list, as it is not running on the host where the `ps` is executed. In fact, it's a good thing that the brackets are redundant, since they might not be present in the command if there happens to be a file named `java` in your current working directory. You really should quote that argument.

I presume that what you intended was to run the entire pipeline on the remote machine, in which case you might have tried:

```
ssh $node "ps -edf | grep [j]ava | awk '{print $2}'"
```

and found that it didn't work. It wouldn't have worked because the `$2` in the awk command will be expanded to whatever `$2` is in your current shell; the `$2` is *not* protected by interior single-quotes. As far as bash is concerned, `$2` is just part of a double quoted string. (And it also would shift the issue of the argument to `grep` not being quoted to the remote host, so you'll have problems if there is a file named `java` in the home directory on the remote host.

So what you actually want is

```
ssh -n $node 'ps -edf | grep "[j]ava" | awk "{print \$2}"'
```

Finally, don't use `PID` as the name of a shell variable. Variable names in all upper case are generally reserved, and it is perilously close to `BASHPID` and `PPID`, which are specific bash variables. Your own shell variables should have lower-case names, as in any other programming language.

Comment: thankyou very very much for the detailed response.

Comment: Awesome. I can just delete mine :) +1

Comment: Better question & answer then the "duplicate" question.